# Developing Firefox Extension, load extension at Dom start

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have been writing Firefox extension but stuck at this point that do we have any simple option for "load extension on DOM start" ,as we have in chrome , in manifest.json file:

```
"run_at": "document_start"
```

my research found **on page load** , **progress listner** like stuff ,but they are a lot of code as compared to **chrome's 'run_at'**.

so are they the only option for Firefox extension developers? or we have somethig else, which I may have missed.

btw , I am using addeventlistner to detect that for now.

Comment: are you writing a firefox web extension or a firefox add on (using jpm) - many chrome extensions need very little (if any) change if you use [firefox web extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions)

Comment: @JaromandaX unfortunately I am writing firefox addon (using jpm)..but yea..thanks for this great information.

Answer (score 0):

Extensions as a whole are loaded when the browser session loads, they are not tied to individual pages.

Within an extension you can inject code into individual tabs via the [page-mod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) or the [tabs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs) modules.

I general I suggest you discard the *this is how chrome APIs work, where is the drop-in replacement in firefox* mindset if you're building SDK addons. The API and addon structure is quite different, so that won't get you far.

@JaromandaX already mentioned webextensions, which mimic chrome apis, but they're still under development.